# Is it possible to change the Products to be termed 'Tours'

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

In the woocommece install, I wish for the Products to be termed 'Tours' (in the backend/admin area) so my client can log in to edit these, and not see them as 'products'

Can you adivse me if this is possible, and so that all admin areas on woocommerce, will portray these as 'tours'

Answer (score 8):

WooCommerce's `woocommerce_register_post_type_product` will let you modify all the parameters that are used to register the post type.

The following code (should be a plugin) should change all the back-end labels. This doesn't change the `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product` URL, but you'd have to change the product type's ID for that and then I doubt WooCommerce would work at all.

I think front-end permalinks are handled in the settings... via Permalinks and also via setting the "shop page", but those *could* be altered via this filter too.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product', 'so_26712459_post_type' );

function so_26712459_post_type( $args ){
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __( 'Tours', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'Tour', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Tours', 'Admin menu name', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'Add Tour', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Tour', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'edit'               => __( 'Edit', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Tour', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Tour', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'view'               => __( 'View Tour', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Tour', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Tours', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Tours found', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Tours found in trash', 'your-custom-plugin' ),
        'parent'             => __( 'Parent Tour', 'your-custom-plugin' )
    );

    $args['labels'] = $labels;
    $args['description'] = __( 'This is where you can add new tours to your store.', 'your-custom-plugin' );
    return $args;
}
```